# ASP.NET 500.19 Error only when a certain empty folder doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net

I have (had) multiple ASP.NET apps in one directory, they talked to each other, and it made development quicker to have them in one folder (one repository) at first. I planned, and am attempting to now separate them into different folders and repositories. Should be easy correct?

The First project `MainApp` never references `OtherApp` and `OtherApp` never references `MainApp` (neither do any files). However, when I remove all of the projects for `OtherApp` from the main folder, `MainApp` will no longer start without error with a "Cannot read configuration file" error, with reference to the `OtherApp.Web\web.config`.

Things get a bit tricky however, because if one folder is left alone (`OtherApp.Web` web project folder), `MainApp` will start correctly, even if `OtherApp.Web\web.config` isn't actually in the folder.

TL;DR - Two ASP.NET apps, neither reference each other. Main application won't start unless a folder exists for the other web project, even if the referenced web.config doesn't actually exist.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, for anyone else with this issue here is how I resolved it.

1. Closed all VS instances.
2. Delete USER\Documents\IISExpress (or rename
   if you want to preserve config)
3. Re-open project Rebuild and run